# How to Incorporate Math.random into an array?

Tags: java

So I'm not sure how to do this problem, write a program that creates an array that can hold 50 integer values. Now it says use a for loop and Math.random() to obviously fill the array with random numbers but idk how to add Math.random into the array. The problem also included when using a for loop with arrays, use the variable "index" as the counter in the loop. Why do I need to include the variable "index," in the for loop? Thanks bunches and please try not to be rude I'm very, very new to programming.

Comment: Do you understand how to create the array and how to assign values into the array?

Comment: How far have you gotten? I mean, do you need help constructing a loop, do you need help constructing an array, do you need help assigning random values to the array? It would be easier to help you effectively if we would know the point at which you are stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring array, suppose you want to have array of 7 integers

`int[] randomNumbers = new int[7];`

now you have `7 integers` referenced by single variable. to access each integer you need an index. indexes start from 0 and end one less than the size of array, in our case `[0-6]`

to initialize arrays

```
randomNumbers[0] = 50;
randomNumbers[1] = 60;
randomNumbers[2] = 40;
randomNumbers[3] = 20;
randomNumbers[4] = 8;
randomNumbers[5] = 6;
randomNumbers[6] = 9;
```

The below picture will illustrate pictorially the above code.

[image: Array Representation]

for math.random() do the following. first import the package using import statement.

```
import java.math.*;
```

since math.random returns a double data type we have to convert it to int. To populate values with random numbers less than 1000 use the below code.

```
 for (int index = 0; index < 50; index++) { 
            randomNumbers[index] = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer you're looking for is this:

```
public int[] randomArray() {
    int[] result = new int[50];
    for (int index = 0; index < 50; index++) {
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 500);
        result[index] = r.nextInt(50);
    }
    return result;
}
```

That method will return an int array of size 50 with each index of the array containing a random number between 0 and 500. Changing the 500 in the code to a different number would change the upper bound on the randomly generated number.

To be clear, you aren't inserting Math.random() into the array; you're just using it to generate random numbers to place in the array.

The "index" variable is included in the for loop because it allows you to iterate over the array. You can see that over the course of the loop, index goes from 0 to 49, covering each index of the array and allowing us to set the value at each index to a random number.

Hopefully that is the answer you're looking for.